# DevExpress XAF and Git issues

Tags: git, devexpress, xaf

just wanted to check if any one can have some recommendation on using XAF  and GIT as the repository, wonder if the merging is a bit difficult or not ?

(of course I will ask to the DevExpress team as well...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am leading expandframework which is an XAF open source project hosted in Github https://github.com/expand/eXpand. I would recommend using GitExtensions VS plugin. In general there are no specific recommendations as far as the merging process. Git does a wonderful job for any kind of project and kdiff3 instaled with GitExtensions is a great tool to resolve any merged conflict

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TFS and select Git as your repo. That way you will not need anything else if you are using Visual Studio 2013 professional. I have used this for [billable hours](http://billable.azurewebsites.net/) my cloud solution based on XAF.